# load different methods from a single class with multiple routes in laminas mezzio

Tags: php, mezzio, laminas

I am trying to route to a single class and load different methods within that class.
Right now i can only manage to load `handle()` inside `SearchInquiryHandler` class. How can i also load `loadThisMethod()` inside `SearchInquiryHandler` from a different route. I am thinking if i can detect the routing url and with proper checking i can load `loadThisMethod()` from my `handle()` method. Any guidance will be hugely helpful.

For a single route here is `routes.php`

```
return static function (Application $app, MiddlewareFactory $factory, ContainerInterface $container) : void {

    $app->post('/api/search/inquiry', App\Handler\SearchInquiryHandler::class, 'api.search.inquiry');
}
```

here is my `SearchInquiryHandler.php`

```
class SearchInquiryHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface {
    protected $template = null;
    private $searchInquiry;
    private $containerName;
    
    public function __construct(TemplateRendererInterface $template, SearchInquiryresultForm $form, SearchInquiry $searchInquiry, $containerName) {

        $this->template = $template;
        $this->searchInquiry= $searchInquiry;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $result = $this->searchInquiry->setInquiryValues();
        return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('app::search-inquiryresult', [
        'entry' => $result,
        ]));
    }

    <!-- HOW TO LOAD THIS METHOD FROM THE ROUTE -->
    public function loadThisMethod(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['ack' => time()]);
    }
```

here is my `SearchInquiryHandlerFactory.php`

```
class SearchInquiryHandlerFactory {

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container) : RequestHandlerInterface
    {
        $dependency   = $container->get(SearchInquiry::class);
        $template = $container->get(LaminasViewRenderer::class);
        $form = $container->get(SearchInquiryresultForm::class);
        return new SearchInquiryHandler($template,$form,$dependency,$container);
    }
}
```

here is my `ConfigProvider.php`

```
public function getDependencies() : array
{
    return [
        'invokables' => [
             ****Some Code here****
         ],
         'factories'  => [
              Handler\SearchInquiryHandler::class => Handler\SearchInquiryHandlerFactory::class,
         ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it ! firstly I was not passing $request to `$this->loadthismethod($request);` inside `handle()`

Secondly if you wish to make multiple route pointing same
`Class SearchInquiryHandler` within `handle()`

you can specify the routes giving unique names

`$app->post('/api/search/inquiry', App\Handler\SearchInquiryHandler::class, 'api.search.inquiry');`

`$app->get('/api/search/test', App\Handler\SearchInquiryHandler::class, 'api.search.test');`

and inside `handle()` you can check routing URL and load different methods as per needs

```
$uri = $request->getUri();
$path = $uri->getPath(); 

if($path!='/api/search/inquiry'){
    return $this->postAjax($request);
}else{
    return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('app::search-inquiryresult', [
        'entry' => $somedata,
    ]));
}
```

OR if you are only going to have only one http request method like `GET` or `POST` to all the methods of a single class, you can do something like this

`$app->get('/api/search[/{action:inquiry|test}[/{id}]]', App\Handler\SearchInquiryHandler::class, 'api.search.inquiry',['GET']);`

I am sure there are better ways to deal this